# syntax error: unexpected end of file in for loop

Tags: string, bash, list, for-loop

I have a very large script, and I'm trying to introduce a for loop.
To test that I have the right syntax, at line 120 say, I have:

```
for M in "1 2 3 4"; do
    echo $M
end
```

However I get the error:

```
./script.sh: line 120: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Even more worryingly, I get the same if I run:

```
for M in $( ls ); do
    echo $M
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no `end` in `bash`. Use `for .. do .. done` .

Comment: What is your hash-bang, i.e., the first line? Your script might be interpreted as a `sh` script instead of a `bash` script if there's only the extension.

Comment: do not ever consciously parse the output of `ls` in a `for` loop, see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: See `help for` for syntax of bash builtin command and please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @sat, that was it - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `done` not `end` to finish a `for` loop

Comment: It's funny how one can't see small errors details like this when coding. Thanks.